# ABPersonViewController error with RubyMotion

Tags: rubymotion

I am having trouble using the `ABPersonViewController` with RubyMotion.  The error I'm getting is

> Objective-C stub for message `setDisplayedPerson:' type`v@:^v' not precompiled. Make sure you properly link with the framework or library that defines this message.

I suspect this is due to RubyMotion not casting to the type IOS expects. I think `ABPersonCreate()` is returning a `CFType` but the `displayedPerson` setter is expecting it to be cast as a `ABRecordRef` (that's just a guess from the error messages)

Here's the sample code to see the problem (based on Apple's QuickContacts sample):

```
#Rakefile
$:.unshift("/Library/RubyMotion/lib")
require 'motion/project'

Motion::Project::App.setup do |app|
  # Use `rake config' to see complete project settings.
  app.name = 'contacts'
  app.frameworks += ['AddressBook', 'AddressBookUI']
end
```

and

```
# app/app_delegate.rb
class AppDelegate
  def application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions)
    window = UIWindow.alloc.initWithFrame(UIScreen.mainScreen.applicationFrame)
    window.rootViewController = UINavigationController.alloc.init
    window.rootViewController.wantsFullScreenLayout = true
    window.makeKeyAndVisible
    true

    # This works
    add_person('Alex', 'Rothenberg')

    # This fails (is it a type casting problem?)
    show_person_view_controller('Rothenberg')
  end

  def show_person_view_controller(name)
    anError = nil

    address_book = ABAddressBookCreate();
    people = ABAddressBookCopyPeopleWithName(address_book, name);
    person = people.first
    picker = ABPersonViewController.alloc.init.autorelease

    picker.personViewDelegate = self
    puts "Should this be an AddressBookRef? #{person.inspect}" # => #<__NSCFType:0x8c3bec0>
    picker.displayedPerson = person
    # The previous line fails
    puts "We never reach this line!"

    self.navigationController.pushViewController(picker, animated:true)
  end

  def add_person(first_name, last_name)
    error = nil
    contact = ABPersonCreate()
    ABRecordSetValue( contact, KABPersonFirstNameProperty, first_name, error )
    ABRecordSetValue( contact, KABPersonLastNameProperty, last_name, error )

    address_book = ABAddressBookCreate()
    ABAddressBookAddRecord( address_book, contact, error )
    ABAddressBookSave( address_book, error )
  end
end
```

When you run it we are able to add to the address book in the `add_person` method but it fails in `show_person_view_controller` on the line `picker.displayedPerson = person`

```
$ rake
     Build ./build/iPhoneSimulator-5.1-Development
  Simulate ./build/iPhoneSimulator-5.1-Development/contacts.app
Should this be an AddressBookRef? #<__NSCFType:0x8da2900>
Objective-C stub for message `setDisplayedPerson:' type `v@:^v' not precompiled. Make sure you properly link with the framework or library that defines this message.
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated

Comment: This looks like a bug (there were some other CoreFoundation bugs related to the AddressBook framework fixed last week, but it still needs a little work). I filed an official support ticket.

Comment: Thanks - I guess I'll wait for an update to RubyMotion then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work properly as of RubyMotion 1.12 (run `sudo motion update`).

> - Fixed a bug where performing Objective-C methods that accept
>     CFType objects
>     would crash the program (ex. [ABPersonViewController setDisplayedPerson:]).

Comment: Are we sure this is fixed, or did it break again? I just hit the exact same problem with RubyMotion 2.6.